# When I try to scroll to from left to right my slider is behave weird?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

When I rotate slider from left to right its pushed to me back to first slider with weird scroll. Can you tell me why its happening?

https://screenrec.com/share/SBid6ohcX4

Sorry I'm not be able to generate this issue on codepen or JS Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolve by removing transition on slick-list class.